# Improving SQL Server subquery performance

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have this view from Microsoft SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT     
    Badgenumber, Date, 
    MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), CAST(CheckIn AS TIME), 100)) AS [CHECK IN], 
    MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), CAST(CheckOut AS TIME), 100)) AS [CHECK OUT]
FROM         
    (SELECT     
         Badgenumber, 
         CONVERT(varchar, CHECKTIME, 105) AS Date, 
         CHECKTIME AS CheckIn, NULL AS CheckOut
     FROM          
         dbo.View_ChronoInOut
     WHERE      
         (CHECKTYPE = 'I')
     UNION ALL
     SELECT     
         Badgenumber, CONVERT(varchar, CHECKTIME, 105) AS Date,  
         NULL AS CheckIn, CHECKTIME AS CheckOut
     FROM         
         dbo.View_ChronoInOut AS View_ChronoInOut_1
     WHERE     
         (CHECKTYPE = 'O')
 ) AS fixTable
GROUP BY 
    Badgenumber, Date
```

It takes 8-12 seconds when fetching data per badgenumber.

Can anyone help me improve this query's performance?

Comment: Firstly please don't use images, use formatted text for data and code. Secondly if you want performance advice we need to see the execution plan using [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Thirdly SSMS is purely a client interface, the view exists in the SQL Server database engine, not in SSMS, and you get the relevant version by running `select @@version`

Comment: o, please bare with me. im just a newbie both here in the site and as a developer. just me give a sec, ill modify it

Comment: Depending on the Edition and Service Pack Level, Microsoft stopped support SQL Server 2008 between 2010 and 2015... you really should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is split the query, because SELECT inside FROM is not the best way to proceed.

For example you can put the select into CTE or temporary table or table variable and use that into FROM